# windows service installed as 64 bit, but run as 32 bit

Tags: c#, windows, service, 64-bit

I have created a windows service with some third party dll's. Those dll's are all 64 bit so I need to set the project to 64 bit and install the service with the 64 bit installer. This all works and is not a problem.

However when I start the service it gives an error on one of the dll's. An Acces Violation Error.

I got this error before when I tried to run the code as 32 bit in another program.

I also copied all code to a simple windows form. There it works like a charm... So it seems to me that for some reason, Windows tries to start the program as a 32 bit program? Is this possible?

I must say, I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to programming...

Edit:
It does show as a 64 bit program in the task manager:
[Platform in Task Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJvbo.png)

Below the error I get:[My error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPvA8.png)

Hope this helps.

Comment: please paste full exception code

Comment: Does it show as a 64 bit process in Task Manager (you have to enable the 'platform' column)?

Comment: @stuartd Yes it shows as a 64 bit service

Comment: @NicoRiff I added the error I get in my question.

Comment: @matthijsvanvliet System.AccessViolationException does not refer to a 32/64 bits issue. Read more about it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.accessviolationexception.aspx

Comment: @NicoRiff I understand that. However, when I create 32 bit winform program and add the same code I get the same error. When I change the winform program to 64 bit, it is works. But not in the windows service...

Comment: @matthijsvanvliet platform diff problems (32 bit vs 64 bit) generate `BadImageFormatException`, **AccessViolationException** are thrown when app tries to read/write to protected memory see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.accessviolationexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Jason thank you for your comment. But how can I fix this? Is there a way to reserve memory for this particular program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in the Dll which gave this error. It now lies by the supplier. I thought, i'd let you know.